# VS2010 Source file 'Project\SharedAssemblyInfo.cs' could not be opened (unspecified error)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I downloaded dicom open source project from Github https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom-samples

I opened the SCU project in visual studio 2010, then by pressing ctrl + shift + s to save the solution (.sln)

After that I downloaded the required nuget PM> `Install-Package fo-dicom -Pre`

When I build the solution I get the above error.

In this screenshot you can see the error (bottom left):

[image: Screenshot]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening this solution by VS 2015

I tried it and it is working as the Nuget is targeting .net framework 4.5.2